# Averaging by time intervals for preceding 5-min bin from datetime

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series, date-arithmetic, binning

I appreciate there are similar questions out there, however, I can't seem to find the correct answer for my query. I have a data set where I want to average the data in one column at 5 minute intervals based on my time stamp, with the averaging starting at the beginning of the hour, for example, average at 10:00 for the preceeding 5 minutes which would be 09:56-10:00.

Here is an example of my data set:

```
data <- structure(list(datetime = c("11/07/2013 19:20", "11/07/2013 19:21", 
"11/07/2013 19:22", "11/07/2013 19:23", "11/07/2013 19:24", "11/07/2013 19:25", 
"11/07/2013 19:26", "11/07/2013 19:27", "11/07/2013 19:28", "11/07/2013 19:29", 
"11/07/2013 19:30", "11/07/2013 19:31", "11/07/2013 19:32", "11/07/2013 19:33", 
"11/07/2013 19:34", "11/07/2013 19:35", "11/07/2013 19:36", "11/07/2013 19:37", 
"11/07/2013 19:38", "11/07/2013 19:39", "11/07/2013 19:40", "11/07/2013 19:41", 
"11/07/2013 19:42", "11/07/2013 19:43", "11/07/2013 19:44", "11/07/2013 19:45"
), met = c(-24.24081371, -24.4280008, -24.35142264, -24.84884114, 
-25.06214408, -25.46749039, -25.44670288, -25.86062294, -26.30899817, 
-26.57565791, -26.6866101, -27.03829228, -27.34621325, -27.91269122, 
-28.60861612, -29.16745075, -28.81285096, -29.89737508, -30.26500716, 
-30.08502411, -31.05084494, -31.21356991, -31.05715444, -32.29645243, 
-32.76946492, -32.69307397)), .Names = c("datetime", "met"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

I have tried the code below, but I haven't been able to get it working the way I want.

```
> data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(data$datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
> groups <- cut(data$datetime, breaks="5 min")
> by(data$met, groups, mean)
groups: 2013-07-11 19:20:00
[1] -24.58624
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
groups: 2013-07-11 19:25:00
[1] -25.93189
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
groups: 2013-07-11 19:30:00
[1] -27.51848
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
groups: 2013-07-11 19:35:00
[1] -29.64554
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
groups: 2013-07-11 19:40:00
[1] -31.6775
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
groups: 2013-07-11 19:45:00
[1] -32.69307
```

These are the correct averages, but the timestamp is the first time stamp of the 5 minute period rather than the last, so 12:01 given by R is actually 12:05 (the period from 12:01 - 12:05). Unfortunately I can't seem to get the output into a format like `12/07/2013 12:05 -19.91691`.

Comment: So `data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(data$datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"); (groups <- cut(data$datetime, breaks="5 min"))` isn't exactly what you were looking for, right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already used `data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(data$datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` and `(groups <- cut(data$datetime, breaks="5 min")` and `met.5min <- by(data$met.day.night, groups, mean)`, however, it is not at the correct interval and it's in a dataframe which I do not know how to export (excuse my ignorance!).

Comment: Please provide expected output. It's not clear whether you want the 5-minute average at every point in your data, or if you want to aggregate so you only have one observation every 5 minutes.

Comment: For example (with different dates), at present I have the output:

`groups: 2013-07-14 12:01:00
[1] -19.91691

groups: 2013-07-14 12:06:00
[1] -20.05351

groups: 2013-07-14 12:11:00
[1] -18.89263`

These are the correct averages, but the timestamp is the first time stamp of the 5 minute period rather than the last, so 12:01 given by R is actually 12:05 (the period from 12:01 - 12:05). Unfortunately I can't seem to get the output into a format like `12/07/2013 12:05  -19.91691`

Comment: I've edited your question to make it reproducible, but the last paragraph does not make sense because you didn't provide those dates.  Please edit your question to explain how your current attempt doesn't provide the desired results.

Comment: This was really an XY problem because you're trying to work around the annoying behavior of `cut()` in not allowing you choose the right end of the interval as the label. You got the actual binning working fine.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Timeseries average based on a defined time interval (bin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837016/timeseries-average-based-on-a-defined-time-interval-bin), whose answers are better idiom (cut is not the most user-friendly function). The only thing different about this question is needing to extract 5-min bins from a datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for working with time series is first to use an existing or implement a library of time series handling routines, which would allow such aggregations in general. I would not write these things again and again on per-case basis. In my earlier role I was driving an implementation of such a library, but well, it is proprietary. Therefore a hint:

- use `split` to split `data$met` at the last/first minute of every hour (indices of those rows can be easily obtained from timestamps with basic R knowledge)
- use `sapply` across the results with an arbitrary aggregation function, g.e. averaging last 5 values
- put results into a timeseries with the same indices you used for split

Having said that, you would really be better off writing a timeseries handling library prodiving general aggregation routines in C.