# Timeseries average based on a defined time interval (bin)

Tags: r, time-series, mean, binning

Here is an example of my dataset. I want to calculate bin average based on time (i.e., ts) every 10 seconds. Could you please provide some hints so that I can carry on?

In my case, I want to average time (ts) and Var in every 10 seconds. For example, I will get an averaged value of Var and ts from 0 to 10 seconds; I will get another averaged value of Var and ts from 11 to 20 seconds, etc.

```
 df = data.frame(ts = seq(1,100,by=0.5), Var = runif(199,1, 10))
```

Any functions or libraries in R can I use for this task?

Comment: you could use the `cut` function to bin your times https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/cut

Comment: This is called a "binned average"

Comment: @PaulH: `cut` is overkill when a simple `group_by(interval=round(df$ts/10))` will do the job...

Comment: @smci Great trick. When wouldn't `cut` be overkill then?

Comment: @PaulH: I guess when we want to pass in custom breaks (or labels). Like non-uniform breaks, such as quantiles, or any other non-uniform breaks you could think up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to calculate a binned average: with base `aggregate`,`by`, with the packages `dplyr`, `data.table`, probably with `zoo` and surely other timeseries packages...

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(interval = round(df$ts/10)*10) %>%
    summarize(Var_mean = mean(Var))
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   interval Var_mean
      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        0 4.561653
 2       10 6.544980
 3       20 6.110336
 4       30 4.288523
 5       40 5.339249
 6       50 6.811147
 7       60 6.180795
 8       70 4.920476
 9       80 5.486937
10       90 5.284871
11      100 5.917074
```

That's the dplyr approach, see how it and data.table let you name the intermediate variables, which keeps code clean and legible.

Comment: Seems like the OP wants the intervals to be reported as e.g., 0 - 10, 10 - 20. Intervals reported as 1, 2, 3... feel misleading

Comment: @PaulH: sure, trivially added by multiplying back by the divisor: `round(df$ts/10)*10`

Comment: @smci how to apply your method to multiple columns? For example, calculate the mean in each column of ts, Var1, Var2 and Var3 based on the binning ts. Here is the example: df = data.frame(ts = seq(1,100,by=0.5), Var1 = runif(199,1, 10), Var2 = runif(199,1, 10), Var3 = runif(199,1, 10))

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang: `summarize(ts_mean = mean(ts), Var1_mean = mean(Var1), Var2_mean = mean(Var2), ...)` It's all in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `df` in the question, convert to a zoo object and then aggregate.

The second argument of `aggregate.zoo` is a vector the same length as the time vector giving the new times that each original time is to be mapped to.  The third argument is applied to all time series values whose times have been mapped to the same value.  This mapping could be done in various ways but here we have chosen to map times (0, 10] to 10, (10, 20] to 20, etc. by using `10 * ceiling(time(z) / 10)`.

In light of some of the other comments in the answers let me point out that in contrast to using a data frame there is significant simplification here, firstly because the data has been reduced to one dimension (vs. 2 in a data.frame), secondly because it is more conducive to the whole object approach whereas with data frames one needs to continually pick apart the object and work on those parts and thirdly because one now has all the facilities of zoo to manipulate the time series such as numerous NA removal schemes, rolling functions, overloaded arithmetic operators, n-way merges, simple access to classic, lattice and ggplot2 graphics, [design](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-design.pdf) which emphasizes consistency with base R making it easy to learn and extensive documentation including [5 vignettes plus help files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) with numerous examples and likely very few bugs given the 14 years of development and widespread use.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df)

z10 <- aggregate(z, 10 * ceiling(time(z) / 10), mean)
```

giving:

```
> z10
      10       20       30       40       50       60       70       80 
5.629926 6.571754 5.519487 5.641534 5.309415 5.793066 4.890348 5.509859 
      90      100 
4.539044 5.480596
```

(Note that the data in the question is not reproducible because it used random numbers without `set.seed` so if you try to repeat the above you won't get an identical answer.)

Now we could plot it, say, using any of these:

```
plot(z10)

library(lattice)
xyplot(z10)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z10)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, I agree with @smci, the `dplyr` and `data.table` approach is the best here. Let me elaborate a bit further.

```
# the dplyr way
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(interval = ceiling(seq_along(ts)/20)) %>% 
  summarize(variable_mean = mean(Var))

# the data.table way
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,list(Var_mean = mean(Var)),
   by =  list(interval = ceiling(seq_along(dt$ts)/20))]
```

I would not go to the traditional time series solutions like `ts`, `zoo` or `xts` here. Their methods are more suitable to handle regular frequencies and frequency like monthly or quarterly data. Apart from `ts` they can handle irregular frequencies and also high frequency data, but many methods such as the print methods don't work well or least do not give you an advantage over `data.table` or `data.frame`.

As long as you're just aggregating and grouping both `data.table` and `dplyr` are also likely faster in terms of performance. Guess `data.table` has the edge over `dplyr` in terms of speed, but you would have benchmark / profile that, e.g. using `microbenchmark`. So if you're not working with a classic R time series format anyway, there's no reason to go to these for aggregating.